# Permanently Remove Current Navigation Column SharePoint 2013

Tags: css, navigation, wiki-pages

I've built a Policy Library for my company by using a Wiki Page Library on SharePoint 2013.

The user is directed between pages via hyperlinks.

I've added the following CSS to a Script Editor to remove the Current Navigation Column from each page (to create more of a website feel for the user):

```
<style type="text/css">  
 #sideNavBox{  
    display:none;  
 }  
</style>
```

Essentially, this has worked pretty well. Occasionally though the Navigation Column appears for a couple of seconds when the user navigates between the pages (i.e. appears unhidden). The page then reverts to the full screen view.

If someone could provide some code to ensure the Navigation is permanently hidden it would be much appreciated. I should mention that I'm a SharePoint novice and do not have access to SharePoint Designer.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to edit the master page and directly hide the parts you don't like in it.
Here's the steps you can follow, *without SharePoint Designer*:

1. Open the master page galery from Site settings.
2. Download the seattle.master file.
3. Rename the local copy.
4. Edit the file locally as needed (remove or comment the entire `<div [...] id="sideNavBox">` tag and its content)
5. Upload you new custom master page back to the master page galery.
6. The tricky part is now to apply this new master page for the site:
   a. If the site has the publishing feature enabled, simply go to the Site settings, and from the Master page link under the Look and feel section select your custom master page.
   b. If you don't have the publishing feature enabled, you may use client C# code, as [this one](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/130814/35604).

[EDIT]
Following your comment about not affecting the whole site, but still keep the navigation hidden on Wiki pages, and if possible with no flicker:
What you could do, while editing the master page, is to set `style="display:none;"` on `<div [...] id="sideNavBox">`. Then you could inject, via JavaScript, your CSS `#sideNavBox{display:block;}`, only in case the URL contains the path your Wiki Library.

Comment: Thanks Evariste. I really appreciate the quick response. As mentioned though, my company doesn't allow us to use SharePoint Designer, so I need to try and find a resolution via CSS that I can add to a script editor web part on the individual pages.

Comment: Ouch, I missed that. I edited my answer to try to provide you with a more relevant answer.

Comment: No problem Evariste. Appreciate you trying to help.

I'm not sure I'm experienced enough to change master pages though - and wouldn't that affect the whole site? I am only responsible for the Wiki Page Library, not the whole SharePoint site.

Ideally, I'm looking for some CSS to apply to the individual pages that will keep the Navigation Column hidden permanently.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint Online I managed to remove the left navigation column in a wiki page by going into Site Settings, Look and Feel, Change the Look and then choosing Current, and changing the template from Seattle to Oslo!